# CSS: How to NOT display on hover

Tags: css, hover

I have

```
.table_header:nth-of-type(5) {display: none;}
```

However, when I hover over .table_header on the page the "nth-of-type(5)" shows up. What do I need to do so that it doesn't even if I hover. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: there might be some other CSS else where (relating to `:hover`)?

Comment: Not much code to test.. but try this might work: `.table_header:nth-of-type(5):hover`

Comment: can you provide sample of your code in jsfiddle.com?

Comment: `.table_header:nth-of-type(5),.table_header:nth-of-type(5):hover {display: none;}` ... but as @KingKing wrote, it's probably overriden somewhere

Comment: try adding `!important`, also are you using nth-of-type correctly - it is an element selector (not a class selector)

Answer (score 0):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/4V2b6/)

Why not use `:not`?

```
.table_header:nth-of-type(5):not(:hover) {display: none;}
```

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot)

> The negation CSS pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation
>   taking a simple selector X as an argument. It matches an element that
>   is not represented by the argument. X must not contain another
>   negation selector, or any pseudo-elements.
>
> The specificity of the :not pseudo-class is the specificity of its
>   argument. The :not pseudo-class does not add to the selector
>   specificity, unlike other pseudo-classes.

Answer (score -1):

you missed the :hover :)

```
.table_header:nth-of-type(5):hover {display: none;}
```